# Windows 8.1 loads mobile versions of some websites

Tags: windows-8.1

I updated to Windows 8.1 a couple of days ago and since then my PC automatically loads mobile versions of some websites. I have tried latest versions of IE, Chrome, FF and all have same issue.

And its not an issue with my PC because my room-mate updated to 8.1 and has same issue.
It is not a problem with our connection either because my other room-mate who is yet to update from 8 to 8.1 can load the site pretty fine.

The site I am talking about is saavn.com. It's a music streaming site.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That web site appears to be doing User-Agent detection (and poorly). I was able to get it to redirect me to its mobile site (and an error page!) by sending a fake IE 11 user agent string.

You can use a User-Agent switching extension for your favorite web browser to work around the problem, or try using IE's Compatibility view options, but ultimately the webmaster of the site needs to fix it. [User-Agent detection is the wrong way to detect a browser's capabilities.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx)

Comment: Yeah...I kinda guesses it must be a fault with website design...but the thing that I don't understand is what does it have to do with updating windows from 8 to 8.1. I think user agent string should not have anything to do with windows version

Comment: The site worked for me with an IE 10 user agent string, but died a horrible death with an IE 11 user agent string.

Comment: Yeah I read that they changed user agent string for IE11 but I don't know why Chrome and FF have issue!

Comment: @tumchaaditya - Because the website doesn't check for those user agents